# how to write a perl regular expression to match a multiline C/C++ preprocessor macro

Tags: perl

I want to write a perl regex to match a C/C++ multiline preprocessor macro.  I came up with

```
\#([\W\w\s\d])*?(\n.*?\\\\)*\n
```

but it doesn't work.

```
#define protected_call(_name, _obj, _method, _args...) \
try { \
    (_obj)->_method(_args); \
} \
catch (exception &e) { \
   ereport(ERROR, \
          errmsg("Error calling %s() in User Function %s at [%s:%d], error code: %d, message: %s", \
                    #_method, (_name), e.filename, e.lineno, e.errorcode, e.what()))); \
} \

catch (...) { \
   ereport(errmsg("Unexpected exception calling %s() User Function in %s", \
                    #_method, (_udsfname)))); \
}
```

Comment: Note: `\w` and `\W` are complements, so the character class `[\W\w]` matches every character, including newlines. I don't think you wanted that. Oh, and could you post some tricky examples of preprocessor directives (!= macro)  to test if solutions work?

Comment: here's one: #define foo_bar(_name,_obj,_method,_args..)  \
    try { \
        (_obj)->_method(_args); \
    } \
    catch (exception &e) { \
       report(  errmsg("Error calling %s() in User Function %s at \[%s:%d], error code: %d, message: %s", \
                        #_method, (_name), e.filename, e.lineno, e.errorcode, e.what()))); \
    } \
    catch (logged_exception &e) { \
        throw; \
    } \
    catch (...) { \
       ereport( errmsg("Unexpected exception calling %s() User Function in %s", \
                        #_method, (_udsfname)))); \
    }

Comment: I am unable to format the example properly.

Comment: [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17111720/edit) your code into the question (with 4-space indent).

Comment: My regexes match everything up to, but not including the second `catch` (i.e. incl. the empty line). Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple solution:

```
/#.*?(?<!\\)\n/s
```

This matches a string up to (including) the first newline that is not preceded by a single backslash.

Example:

```
my $regex = qr/#.*?(?<!\\)\n/s;

my @test_cases = (<<'---', <<'---', <<'---');
#include <foo.h>
spam
---
foo # bar\
baz
eggs
---
irrelevant line
foo #bar\
baz  \\
qux
# second directive to confuse
quux
---

my @solutions = (
  "#include <foo.h>\n",
  "# bar\\\nbaz\n",
  "#bar\\\nbaz  \\\\\nqux\n",
);

use Test::More 'no_plan';
for my $i (0 .. $#test_cases) {
  $test_cases[$i] =~ /($regex)/;
  is $1, $solutions[$i];
}
```

#### Edit: `define`s

You now said you only want to match `define`s. For that, we have to modify the beginning of our regex to match an additional condition. I will assume that a `define` processor directive is encountered when the `#` is immediately followed by `define`. I will not assert that there is a valid macro definition on the line:

```
/#define\b.*?(?<!\\)\n/s
```

---

Your regex `\#([\W\w\s\d])*?(\n.*?\\\\)*\n` can be better written

```
my $regex = qr/
  \# .*?
  (?: \n [^\n]*? [\\][\\] )*
  \n
/xs;
```

This starts the match at the first `#`. Then, it matches as few characters at possible for a successful match, but imposes no constraints. The next group may match as often as it likes.   It starts with a newline, any non-newline characters, and ends with a double backslash. This has to be followed by a newline, upon which the match may succeed.

It doesn't require the first line of the directive to end with a backslash before it tests for further continuation lines. The continuation escape is the double backslash `\\` for some reason, but is only recognized from the second line onward. This will match the following as preprocessor directives (matching string enclosed in `→...←`):

```
foo →# bla bla
bla bla\\
←foo foo
foo
```

or

```
foo →#bla bla\\
← foo foo
foo foo
```

I.e. it matches the first line regardless of anything, and keeps matching lines as long as they end on a double backslash.

Comment: This matches #include's as well which I don't want. Given a c++ file , I need to extract all macros out of it.

Comment: Oh, you only want `define`s? I can do that…

Comment: great so  this matches all the macros that i care about but it also matches the #define' s that I don't care abt like #define USER_SUPPORT

Comment: @user2486585 Then how do I know which macros you are interested in, and which are irrelevant? Your question makes no such distinction.

Comment: I want to match macros that have function arguments. For example #define func_name( _x, _y) and not something like #define user_support

Comment: Then it should be sufficient to match the opening paren, e.g. with `#define\s+\w+\s*\(...`.

Answer (score 1):

`.*?` can easily "malfunction" if you have more than one in a pattern, so you might need to replace

```
 /^\s*#.*?(?<!\\)\n/ms
```

with

```
 /^\s*#(?:[^\\]+|\\[^\n])*(?:\\\n(?:[^\\]+|\\[^\n])*)*/m
```

Same with whitespace added for readability:

```
 /
    ^\s*\#
    (?: [^\\]+ | \\[^\n] )*
    (?:
       \\\n
       (?: [^\\]+ | \\[^\n] )* 
    )*
/xm
```

---

Note that none of these solutions will work correct unless you make sure it starts matching between tokens rather than in the middle of one such as a string literal.

```
  char *s = "
  #not actually a pragma
  ";
```